How to bypass ECS task definition override character limit?
I'm working with ECS task definitions and I'm running into an issue with the task override character limit of 8192 characters. I need to pass commands that will be executed in the ECS container, but they exceed this limit.
I came across this Stack Overflow post before:
increase ECS task definition override character limit 8192
One of the answers suggests placing the commands in a shell script and referencing it in the task definition. I'd like to know how to properly set up the task definition to reference an external shell script in order to avoid hitting the character limit error.
Could you provide guidance on how to implement this approach?
Specifically, I'm interested in:

Where should I store the shell script?
How do I reference it correctly in the ECS task definition?
Are there any best practices or considerations I should keep in mind when using this method?

Any additional insights or alternative solutions would also be greatly appreciated.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

"I'd like to know how to properly set up the task definition to reference an external shell script in order to avoid hitting the character limit error.:" There is no official method of doing that. You just need to change your command to download a script from S3 or something, and then execute it after the download. You could even configure your container startup script to do that, based on an environment variable, and then you wouldn't even need to override the command anymore, just an environment variable.

@MarkB
Thank you!
I've solved the issue with the limitation!
